# Cannot add properties to an object - Node.js/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to check if a user account has already been created in either User model or TempUser model, however encounter an issue where I cannot add a found value to an object in order to process the conditional check.

Please check the code below and comments:

```
exports.isRegistered = function(userModel, tempUserModel, username){
    var obj = {}; //creating an empty object to add the found results later
    userModel.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(user){
            obj.user = user;
            console.log(obj); // doesn't fire as no user was found found
        }else{
            tempUserModel.findOne({username: username}, function(err, tempUser){
                if(err) throw err;
                obj.tempUser = tempUser;
                console.log(obj); // returns object with a tempUser as it was found
            });
        }
    });
    console.log(obj); //returns an empty object again.
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the code and your issues, I can come these conclusions:

> doesn't fire as no user was found found

Are you sure you `User` collections has these object with given username? I don't think so. Please check if you're providing the correct value of `username` and a doc exists in User collection with that value.

> returns an empty object again.

Callbacks are always a little tricky to understand. 
Ok, so let's break the steps you did in your code:

1. Declared `obj`, as blank object
2. Called `findOne` on a model
3. Logged `obj`, which showed you {},i.e, blank object

It happened because 2nd step ran **Asynchronously**.
This is how your code flowed,

Declared obj -> Called FineOne (but callback is still not executed) -> Logged Obj (Still Blank) -> Callback of FineOne operation executed and populated some value in Obj

I hope it's little more clear now. I would suggest you read these blogs:

- http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/
- http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Let me in the case of any clarification.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and references, will try to understand everything better.

Answer (score 1):

You get an empty object because those two queries are asynchronous. In order to return the proper object with the found parameter you can return it inside queries' scope. You can use Promises to achieve this.

I would build a generic function to perform a find on the two collections:

```
exports.isRegistered = (userModel, tempUserModel, username) => {
    let usr = {};
    findUser(username, userModel).then((user) => {
       if(user) {
           usr.user = user;
           return usr;
       }
       findUser(username, tempUserModel).then((user) => {
         if(user) {
           usr.tempUser = user;
           return usr;
         }
         return ({error : 'User Not Found'});
       }).catch((err) => {
          return err;
       });
    }).catch((err) => {
       return err;
    });
}

const findUser = (username, collection) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      collection.findOne({username : username}).then((err, user) => {
        if(err) return reject(err);
        if(user) return resolve(user);
      });
    });
}
```

You can also put both of these calls inside an array, resolve both of them and joining their results, so you can perform them faster.